# Using a Token-ring network card instead of a router (?)

Tags: networking, windows-xp, router, network-share, internet

I have cable, and the modem only has 1 network plug-in.  They said I could buy my own router if I wanted to hook up two computers to it.  I have an IBM Turbo 16/4 Token-Ring PC Card 2, which was in the laptop when I bought it, and the laptop also has the typical network plug (not a PC Card). Is there a way I could run the laptop as a server, and plug my desktop into the laptop, so they both have internet without my having to buy a router? (I realize routers are as cheap as $30.)  Both computers run Windows XP Pro SP3. (I also have an 10/100 Etherjet Cardbus card (PC Card)).

Thanks.

Comment: As a geek exercise, I'm sure it'll be interesting, but I thought token ring was slower than 100Base-T, so why bother if Ethernet is quicker?

Comment: TOKEN RING?!? Ack... MY EYES! The goggles-- they do nothing!

Comment: I was just hoping to use one of the cardbus cards, rather than buying a router.  The answer I selected below will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to have something else that understands token ring.

You don't say what kind of interface is in the desktop, but I'm guessing it's Ethernet. You could connect like this:

```
cable-modem <-ethernet-> laptop-eth-0 <laptop> laptop-eth-1 <-ethernet-> desktop
```

And turn on Internet sharing in the laptop.

Comment: Thanks.  The other card I mentioned, the 10/100 Etherjet Cardbus card, is an ethernet card, and I found the drivers for it.  ICS (Windows "Internet Connection Sharing") will do what I need.

Answer (score 2):

Token Ring and Ethernet are very, very different. Attempting to connect a Token Ring jack to an Ethernet jack may result in the destruction of either or both.